# how to use a struct member as argument

Tags: c, struct

I am attempting to use a member of a struct call channels to be used in higher level functions. Is is possible to have only one argument?

```
typedef struct {
    int size;
    Port_PadDriver padDriver; //pad driver speed
    UserConfig *pinTable;
    Port_Mode defaultmode;
    Port_State defaultstate; //set, reset, toggle port
} DefaultConfig;    

typedef struct {
    uint32 Channel;
    Port_Pin *pin;
    Port_Mode mode;
    Port_State state; //set, reset, toggle port
} UserConfig;

void IO_init(void) {
    DefaultConfig defaultConfig;//create object
    initconfig(&defaultConfig);//set init settings
    userConfig(&defaultConfig);//overwrite settings with users settings with 
a struct array
}
```

is it possible to create a IO_SetPinHigh(int channelnum); to be used in the IO_init(void) to change specific pins.

Comment: The variable `defaultConfig` should be a global variable, or at least the address of this variable should be passed to the `IO_init` function.  Currently, any configuration that you will do will be lost after completing the Init function.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to struct members with the `.` operator. By doing this, you can reference this member individually like any other variable:

```
IO_SetPinHigh(defaultConfig.channel);
```

Of course, if you want to modify this variable, you'll have to pass a pointer to it:

```
IO_SetPinHigh(&defaultConfig.channel);
```

Comment: Unlike in C++ there is no "passing by reference" in C

Comment: @Jabberwocky that was bad phrasing on my part. If you want to modify an int passed to a function, you need to pass a pointer to it. Edited my answer accordingly.